# Transform and Pivoting by Grouping in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables in MsAccess as follow:

```
Students(ID, Name, Class)
Subjects (ID, Name)
Marks (ID, StudentName[ID of Student], Subject.ID)
```

and following relation:

```
Marks.Subject = Subjects.ID
Marks.StudentID = Students.ID
```

I need to Display following output table:

```
--+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------etc..
   Student Name    Subject1Name    Subject2Name   Subject1Name
--+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------etc..

    jkki LastN       15                50               30
    XYZ LastN        25                60               70
    gui LastN        05                30               50
```

Currently I have Follwing SQL:

```
Transform Marks.Obtained
SELECT Students.Name, Marks.Obtained
FROM (Students INNER JOIN (Marks INNER JOIN Subjects ON Marks.Subject = Subjects.ID)
ON Students.ID = Marks.StudentName)
GROUP BY  Students.Name, Marks.Obtained
Pivot Subjects.Name
```

Which gives repeated output of the same name as follow:

```
--+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------etc..
   Student Name    Subject1Name    Subject2Name   Subject1Name
--+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------etc..

    jkki LastN       15               
    jkki LastN                          20      
    jkki LastN                                         05
```

Removing Group by Marks.Obtained from SQL gives following error: 
"you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Obtained' as a part of aggregate function"

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: it would help getting an answer faster and with higher quality if you add the RDBMS tag (MsAccess) to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Transform` should have an aggregation function.  Try this:

```
Transform MAX(Marks.Obtained)
SELECT Students.Name
FROM (Students INNER JOIN
      (Marks INNER JOIN
       Subjects
       ON Marks.Subject = Subjects.ID)
     ON Students.ID = Marks.StudentName)
GROUP BY Students.Name
Pivot Subjects.Name
```